# How to extract a variable that is calculated in the constructor of an object in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, oop, variables, object, constructor

I am relatively new to OOP (as well as new to Python), and I am currently trying to create objects that are instantiated when passed in a certain text file. While this text file gets parsed and organized into my desired data structure (which is a dictionary, in this case), I also would like to have another variable present that counts the number of entries from the original text file that were not admitted into the dictionary.

When the object is instantiated, I can then access the dictionary created in the constructor of the object because I put a **getitem** method. However, I can't seem to access the variable I calculated in the constructor. I have tried to write a new method that returns the variable, and it does not work. It only says that I have returned this "bound method ClassName.get_unregistered of <**main**.ClassName object at 0x11cfaaf10"

Here is an example of my current class structure:

```
class ClassName(object):
    def __init__(self):
        textfile= 'sometextfileofsequences.txt'
        self.dict_of_sequences= SeqIO.to_dict(SeqIO.parse(textfile, "fasta"))
        unregistered_sequences=0
        for name in self.dict_of_sequences.keys():
            #the sequences gets evaluated here. if it matches a certain condition,
            #then it is included in the dictionary. Or else it is left out.
            if (self.dict_of_sequences[name])== condition
                self.dict_of_sequences[name]= sequence
            else:
                 self.dict_of_sequences.pop(name, None)
                 unregistered_sequences+=1

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.dict_of_sequences[key]

    def get_unregistered(self):
        return unregistered_sequences
```

A lot of my coding experience has been garnered through online sources, so there is a lot of theory and concepts that I don't fully grasp. I have tried to read a lot about objects in coding and what techniques they entail, but this ostensibly simple problem has stumped me quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

1) Define a class with the `class` keyword, not `def`.

2) Any variable which isn't prefaced by `self.` is considered local during the instantiation and goes out of scope after the constructor is finished. Replace all instances of `unregistered_sequences` with `self.unregistered_sequences`.

Comment: I tried that, but now when I instantiate the object and run the method get_unregistered on it, it returns
**unbound method ClassName.get_unregistered**.

Do you know why?

Comment: See my updated answer. You should be defining a class with `class`, not `def`.

Comment: Whoops, I made a mix-up between class and def. My original code has the correct terminology in place, and I'll edit my code above to reflect this. 

But do you know why self.unregistered_sequences will not give me an integer count, but instead an unbound method?